# How to make git asked user and password

Tags: git

I have to install git on server and i want it ask for username and password who is updating the code.
I have tried these cmd but didn't find these useful

```
git config -l
```

Currently git is not asking and updating the code with my id only.Can anybody help me for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use `git config credential.helper store` to store your username and password?

You can try disabling the git credentials storage by -

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Comment: Yes it works thanks but its opening gui now i only want to enter in cmd line

Comment: are you using windows or linux?

Comment: window only window

Comment: i am using git bash